# jQuery Mobile stop listen on 'vmouseup' when I make a small 'swipe/movement' with phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

Got some functionallity if it's a 'vmousedown' or 'vmouseup' event.
The problem is that when I 'vmousedown' with a win8 mobile and while pressing the screen, moveing my finger a bit and releases, it doesn't fire the 'vmouseup' event. And then my tapTimer whont be reseted. 
Havn't tested with other phones yet but I dont know if it is the OS that prevent it or if it is jQuery Mobile. If it is jQM then its proberly fixable.
I tried every possible event on [jquery mobile event page](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/).
But their isn't anyone that react on my finger movement. One last thought I have is to deal with it with X and Y possitions.
But it feels like alot of checking if a timer is on when clicking around the page even if it isn't of this purpose.

```
    $('#element').on('vmousedown vmouseup', function(e) {
    if (e.type === 'vmousedown') {
           tapTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            isTapHold = true;
            $this.find('.ui-block-b').find('li').addClass('gggg');
        }, 1500);
    } else {
           clearTimeout(tapTimer);
    if (!isTapHold) {
                //
            } else {
                $.mobile.silentScroll(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving your finger after 'vmousedown' fires the 'vmousemove' event. If you want the 'vmouseup' to fire, you should prevent the default action of the vmousemove event using preventDefault() method.

You can add:

```
$('#element').on('vmousemove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```